# getCellSignalStrength() always reports same value: -51

Tags: android

I'm trying to read the actual cell signal strength from my Samsung S6, but getDbm() always returns -51b (type is WCDMA).
(I call that function in a loop and every time it is -51.)

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) APIDispatcher.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
for (final CellInfo info : telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()) {
    if (info instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
        CellSignalStrengthGsm gsm = ((CellInfoGsm) info).getCellSignalStrength();
        result = gsm.getDbm();
        Log.i("CellSignalStrengthGsm", "strength:"+result);
    } else if (info instanceof CellInfoCdma) {
        CellSignalStrengthCdma cdma = ((CellInfoCdma) info).getCellSignalStrength();
        result = cdma.getDbm();
        Log.i("CellSignalStrengthCdma", "strength:"+result);
    } else if (info instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
        CellSignalStrengthWcdma wcdma = ((CellInfoWcdma) info).getCellSignalStrength();
        result = wcdma.getDbm();
        Log.i("CellSignalStrengthWcdma", "strength:"+result);
    } else if (info instanceof CellInfoLte) {
        CellSignalStrengthLte lte = ((CellInfoLte) info).getCellSignalStrength();
        result = lte.getDbm();
        Log.i("CellSignalStrengthLte", "strength:"+result);
    }
}
```

The "SIM Card Status" of my mobile reports -103 dBm (+/- 2 dBm).
I never get a different value other than -51.

I also tried to install a listener with:

```
telephonyManager.listen(new SignalStrengthListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
```

but the callbak is never being called.

I have no idea anymore. Maybe you?

Comment: have you granted ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission?

Comment: Yes.  
But when I remove that permission I get exactly the same results!
 
How can I be sure that the permission is really granted?

Comment: for granted I mean asked at runtime, not just in the manifest

Comment: my target sdk version is 21. manifest permission should be sufficient, shouldn't it?

Comment: you're right it should be sufficient, maybe you're missing some other permission in the manifest..?